# postgresql column sums across a join, grouped by another column

Tags: postgresql, join, sum

Suppose I have the following PostgreSQL tables:

table: `foo`:

```
foo_id, baz, amount
--------------------
f1, b1, 500
f2, b1, 500
f3, b2, 1000
f4, b3, 100
```

table: `bar`:

```
bar_id, foo_id, amount
--------------------
br1, f1, 10
br2, f1, 10
br3, f1, 10
br4, f2, 10
br5, f2, 10
br6, f3, 750
br7, f3, 250
br8, f4, 90
br9, f4, 9
```

My goal is to sum up `foo.amount` and `bar.amount`, and find the difference, grouped by `foo.baz`.

Example results:

```
baz, sum_foo_amount, sum_bar_amount, diff_foo_bar
-------------------------------------------------
b1, 1000, 50, 950
b2, 1000, 1000, 0
b3, 100, 99, 1
```

I managed to get the expected results using a couple CTE's -- one summing up `foo`, and one summing up `bar` -- then selecting from `foo` and grouping.  But I'm actually dealing with ~1m rows for `bar` and it was *not* performant to say the least.

I feel confident I could cobble something together eventually, but I'm curious for insights on patterns or approaches I may not see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not one of my proudest questions *or* answers, but posting the currently in-use solution for posterity:

```sql
select    
    baz,
    foo_sum,
    bar_sum,
    (foo_sum - bar_sum) as difference
from    
    (
    with x as (
        select           
            foo.baz as baz,
            cast(foo.amount as decimal) as foo_sum,
            cast(sum(bar.amount) as decimal) as bar_sum
        from bar
        inner join foo on bar.foo_id = foo.foo_id        
        group by bar.foo_id, foo.baz, foo.amount
    )
select       
       x.baz as baz,
       sum(x.foo_sum) as foo_sum,
       sum(x.bar_sum) as bar_sum
from x
group by x.baz
    ) as foo_bar_calculations;
```

Producing the results:

```
 baz | foo_sum | bar_sum | difference 
-----+---------+---------+------------
 b2  |    1000 |    1000 |          0
 b3  |     100 |      99 |          1
 b1  |    1000 |      50 |        950
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
select 
    a.baz, a.amount,b.amount,a.amount-b.amount
from 
    (select baz,sum(amount) as amount from foo group by baz) as a,
    (select foo_id,sum(amount) as amount from foo group by foo_id) as b
where
    a.baz = b.foo_id
```

Comment: My apologies @Philippe, I had incorrect table data for `bar.foo_id`; it does *not* point at `foo.baz`, but at `foo.foo_id`.  So the last `where` will not work from your -- kindly supplied -- solution.  I've updated it.

Comment: I'm sorry but id on't understand the relation between the two tables.The sum of b1 in foo table is ok. But how can you have"50" in bar when you have only 30 for f1 ??? There's something wrong. Can you explain ?

Comment: The 50 comes from `bar.foo_id --> foo.foo_id` (`f1` and `f2`) and then the sum of `bar.amount` grouped by `foo.baz` (`b1`).

Comment: What's the relation between foo and bar. In that table's description you can't know that foo.b1 = sum(bar.f1) + sum(bar.f2). There's no unique key to make the relation you want.

Comment: I appreciate you sticking with this.  I have found a solution, but am still curious about better approaches.  Look at first 5 rows of `bar`.  They all FK to either `foo.f1` or `foo.f2`.  One piece of information needed is the sum of `foo.f1 --> amount` + `foo.f2 --> amount`.  What is important about `foo.f1` and `foo.f2` is that they share `foo.baz = b1`.  Think of them as "deposits" and `foo.baz=b1` means they went into the same account.  Then think of `bar` rows as "withdrawals"; they were related to deposits (`foo.foo_id`), but they "came from" the same account `b1`.